# Replace Multiple similar CTEs with a Loop in SQL

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

i have a question regarding postgres and sql, but first of all i have to say im not very well versed in SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

So the company im working for uses a postgres DB and most querys have a lot of WITH statements, for example the sales of each year have their own with statement in that query. At the end of the query these are then joined.

Im trying to reduce the amount of code the query has for learning purposes and just because it annoys me to see that much code doing nearly the same.

Is their a way to summarize them into some kind of function like in other programming languages? I know there are functions and procedures in postgres db, but i was unable to find a suitable solution for the problem. In the code snippet below im only posting the CTEs that i want to outsource into some kind of function. Preferably i do not want to make drastic changes to the code since im not the original author of it.

Best Regards

```
--####################################################### Sales #######################################################
    
, sales_2018 as (
        select
            article_id,         article_number,         sum(position_total) as netto,       sum(quantity) as quantity
        from 
            gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel
        left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel."ordertime"::date
        
        where 
            year_reporting::double precision = 2018     and order_status <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
        group by
            article_id, article_number  )


, sales_2019 as (
        select
            article_id,         article_number,         sum(position_total) as netto,       sum(quantity) as quantity
        from 
            gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel
        left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel."ordertime"::date
        
        where 
            year_reporting::double precision = 2019     and order_status <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
        group by
            article_id, article_number  )
    
    
, sales_2020 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where orderyear = '2020'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )
    
, sales_2021 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where orderyear = '2021'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )


, sales_2021_ytd as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where orderyear = '2021'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt') and order_creationdate <= now() -  interval '1 year' * (extract(year from now()) - 2021) 
    group by article_number )
    
, sales_2022 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where orderyear = '2022'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )
    
, sales_2022_ytd as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition      
    where orderyear = '2022'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt') and order_creationdate <= now() - interval '1 year' * (extract(year from now()) - 2022) 
    group by article_number )

, sales_2023_ytd as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where orderyear = '2023'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt') and order_creationdate <= now() - interval '1 year' * (extract(year from now()) - 2023) 
    group by article_number )

, revenue_2018 as (
        SELECT 
            article_id,         article_number,         sum(position_total) as revenue,     sum(quantity) as quantity
        FROM 
            "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" 
        left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" ."delivered_earliest"::date
        where 
            "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" ."delivered_earliest" is not null
            and "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" ."order_status" <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
            and time.year_reporting::integer = 2018
        group by article_id, article_number  )


, revenue_2019 as (
        SELECT 
            article_id,         article_number,         sum(position_total) as revenue,     sum(quantity) as quantity
        FROM 
            "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" 
        left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" ."delivered_earliest"::date
        where 
            "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" ."delivered_earliest" is not null
            and "gh_consolidated"."bestellungen_artikel" ."order_status" <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
            and time.year_reporting::integer = 2019
        group by article_id, article_number  )  
    
    
, revenue_2020 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as revenue,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where date_part('year', delivered_earliest_date_new) = 2020 and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )

, revenue_2021 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as revenue,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where date_part('year', delivered_earliest_date_new) = 2021 and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )
    

, revenue_2021_ytd as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as revenue,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where  date_part('year', delivered_earliest_date_new) = 2021  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt') and delivered_earliest_date_new <= now() - interval '1 year' * (extract(year from now()) - 2021) 
    group by article_number )
    
, revenue_2022 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as revenue,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where date_part('year', delivered_earliest_date_new) = 2022 and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )
    
, revenue_2022_ytd as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as revenue,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where date_part('year', delivered_earliest_date_new) = 2022  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt') and delivered_earliest_date_new <= now() - interval '1 year' * (extract(year from now()) - 2022) 
    group by article_number )
    
, revenue_2023_ytd as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as revenue,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where date_part('year', delivered_earliest_date_new) = 2023  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt') and delivered_earliest_date_new <= now() - interval '1 year' * (extract(year from now()) - 2023) 
    group by article_number )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, keep in mind that any time you use the terms *SQL and Loop* together, you are most likely doing it wrong. SQL by its very nature processes all the data. You need to think in set of data, not individual data entries. That is why there is not loop statement in SQL. THink of it this wat *SQL automatically loops - always*. (Yes there are exceptions that need `plpgsql`, but they are not very common).  
 Wherever the result set, `Join` conditions, and `Where` predicates are the same, other that a common where predicate, you can combine the common predicates. For example the section:

```
, sales_2018 as (
        select
            article_id,         article_number,         sum(position_total) as netto,       sum(quantity) as quantity
        from 
            gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel
        left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel."ordertime"::date
        
        where 
            year_reporting::double precision = 2018     and order_status <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
        group by
            article_id, article_number  )


, sales_2019 as (
        select
            article_id,         article_number,         sum(position_total) as netto,       sum(quantity) as quantity
        from 
            gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel
        left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel."ordertime"::date
        
        where 
            year_reporting::double precision = 2019     and order_status <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
        group by
            article_id, article_number  )
```

can be reduced to:

```
, sales_2018_2019 as
        ( select article_id, article_number, sum(position_total) as netto, sum(quantity) as quantity
            left join "gh_consolidated"."vt_myzeit" as time on time.ansi = gh_consolidated.bestellungen_artikel."ordertime"::date     
           where year_reporting::double precision in (2018, 2019)   
             and order_status <> 'Storniert / Abgelehnt'
           group by article_id, article_number
        )
```

However you could not combine:

```
, sales_2020 as (
    select 
        article_number,
        sum(sales_price_net_eur_inkl_order_pos_discount) as sales,
        sum(quantity) as quantity
    
    from "02_business_layer".orderposition
    where orderyear = '2020'  and auftragsstatus_stf1 not IN ('Abgesagt')
    group by article_number  )
```

as the result is different, as are `Join` conditions and `Where` predicates.

There are a couple disturbing (at least unusual) aspects:

- Seems you are getting annual information but none of the results sets contain the year. Particularly for the CTE that indicate`..._ytd_...` (year_to_date?).
- Why cast `year_reporting` as double precision  then comparing to an integer constant (`year_reporting::double precision = 2019`). But, at
  other places the same field cast to integer. You might want to standard your conversion/comparisons.
- Like to be others. I just noticed the above on a glance.

Note: Nothing Tested.

Comment: Hi @Belayer,

first off thanks for your reply and effort of answering, i should have explained that the code above is for visualization purposes. The code is used in metabase to illustrate important factors for my organization. Thats why for example the year was not contained. As for the casting thanks for your info i set integer as standard. I thank you for your reply.